# How do I know which Realm calls throw in Swift?

Tags: swift2, realm

I'm using Swift 2, Xcode 7 and OSX 10.11. I'm new at Swift & Realm!

The Realm documentation for 0.95.3 shows this:

```
let mydog = Dog()
mydog.name = "Rex"
println("name of dog: \(mydog.name)")

// Persist your data easily
let realm = Realm()
realm.write {
  realm.add(mydog)
}
```

Yet in Xcode 7, this generates an error at 'let realm = Realm()':

```
Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.
```

Neither the example code or the API describe any of the calls as causing a throw - why not? Do I need a try statement with every Realm call or am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Realm documentation has not been completely updated yet to Swift 2. When you have a look at the `Realm.swift` file you can see that a lot of methods are throwable now.

For example here is the `write:` method

```
public func write(block: (() -> Void)) throws {
    try rlmRealm.transactionWithBlock(block)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the `Realm` constructor that throws

This will solve it.

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
```